# Solve to get a value for $y.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Please help me solve this question.
Solve for y.

$1.\quad a^x=b^y=c^z$

$2.\quad b^2=ac$

I figured out that $b^{2+y}=a^{x+1}c^{z+1}$, but I am not able to go further, please help me.

Comment: $y=\frac{log(c^2)}{log(b)}$

Comment: you have more equations than needed...$y=x.log(a)/log(b)=z.log(c)/log(b)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting $$a^x=b^y=c^z=t$$ so we get (using $b^2=ac$)
$t^{2/y}=t^{1/x+1/z}$ and we get $$\frac{2}{y}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{z}$$

Comment: I substituted obtain by get as I had to edit at least 6 characters.

Comment: What if $x=2, b=1, y=1, c=1, z=1$.... The LHS in the last equation is $2$ but the RHS is $1.5$! Please explain.

Comment: The answer for y is $$y = \frac{2xz}{x+z}$$